# how to return std::seed_seq object from a function

Tags: c++, c++11

How to write a function return `std::seed_seq` object?

The code below don't work.

```
std::seed_seq f(){
    return {0};
}

std::seed_seq s = f();  /* error C2280: 
                           'std::seed_seq::seed_seq(const std::seed_seq &)':
                           attempting to reference a deleted function
                         */
```

Comment: Which compiler is this? Seems to [compile fine here](http://cpp.sh/7nfwl). That definitely should not invoke a copy construction because of [RVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: @CoryKramer VC++2017

Comment: @CoryKramer your compiler may be using guaranteed copy-elision, not available in C++11

Comment: Could you force the behavior with `std::seed_seq s = std::move(f());`?

Comment: @CoryKramer This won't work either - A move is not an ellision, and the move-constructor of `std::seed_seq` is implicitly deleted by the explicit deletion of the copy constructor.

Comment: @CoryKramer [Can repro here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e4414c11e9f7887)

Comment: @CoryKramer Tried, no luck.

Comment: What do you aim to do @J.Doe

Comment: Why not return a `std::initializer_list` and have the object constructed at the call site from that?

Comment: @coincoin It's like a seeds lookup table. But huge. For a given lookup key, the seeds should not change. I can just return a vector. But I think a seed_seq would be much better.

Comment: @J.Doe What do you use the seed for after retrieving them from your lookup table? Maybe you could return const reference if it suits your needs.

Comment: I copied the code of std::seed_seq and removed the delete declaration. Hope I didn't violate anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Apparently the Standard does not see a reason to make it copyable, as it is just a temporary object to generate proper seed sequence out of small input. Why it is not moveable is a bit questionable, but probably the answer is within the same frame of reasoning as for the copy.

There are few workarounds though:

1. Use the heap i.e. return a pointer to the seed sequence:

   ```
   auto seq = std::make_unique<std::seed_seq> (/*...*/);
   // ...
   return seq;
   ```
2. After generation, instead of returning the `std::seed_seq` object itself, just copy its content into another store.

   ```
   std::seed_seq seq (/*...*/);
   // ...
   std::vector<std::seed_seq::result_type> seeds (seq.size ());
   seq.param (seeds.begin ());
   ```
3. The other way around. Store the input to `std::seed_seq` instead. That's what I did at the end. There is no real difference between whether you will keep what was stored or what you are going to store there - the Standard guarantees that. It is just that you can decide to do something with the seeds before passing them to `std::seed_seq` e.g. setting them to concrete values for debug purposes.